# About OMP barrier and dynamic array

Tags: c++, c, openmp, barrier

Does OMP ensure that the contents of an dynamic array is up-to-date and is visible to all threads after an OMP barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A barrier causes all threads' view of all accessible memory to be made consistent; that is, it implicitly flushes the entire state of the program.

Answer (score 0):

if your array is out of the #pragma omp parallel construct, it will automatically accessible & share by all the thread.

But the way he is update by the thread only depend if your algo and the synchro mechanism you use to ensure the correctness.